# Функция в Python не вызывается

Tags: python, функции

Всем здравствуйте! У меня не вызывается функция `attack_zone()`. В чём моя ошибка?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from threading import Thread
from playsound import playsound 

kill_boss=False
robot_health = 100

def attack():
    global robot_health,kill_boss
    if robot_health==0:
        kill_boss=True
    else:
        robot_health-=1
    
kill = False

fight = Tk()
fight['bg']='black'
fight.geometry("400x400")
fight.title('Битва')
w = 500
h=500
Canvas = Canvas(bg='black')
Canvas.pack()

def kot(a):
    messagebox.showinfo('Заголовок',a) 

global a1
global a2
global b1
global b2
global c1
global c2
global d1
global d2

a1= 15
a2=15
d1=25
d2=25
c1=a1
c2=d2
b1=d1
b2=d1

player = Canvas.create_rectangle(a1,a2,d1,d2,fill='red')

Button(fight,bg='red',comand=attack()).pack()

def down():
    global a1
    global a2
    global b1
    global b2
    global c1
    global c2
    global d1
    global d2
    Canvas.move(player,0,10)
    d2=+1
    c2=+1

def up():
    global a1
    global a2
    global b1
    global b2
    global c1
    global c2
    global d1
    global d2
    Canvas.move(player,0,-10)
    d2=-10
    c2-=10

def left():
    global a1
    global a2
    global b1
    global b2
    global c1
    global c2
    global d1
    global d2
    Canvas.move(player,-10,0)
    c1=-10
    d1-=10

def right():
    global a1
    global a2
    global b1
    global b2
    global c1
    global c2
    global d1
    global d2
    Canvas.move(player,10,0)
    c1=+10
    d1=+10

global x1
global x2
global y1
global y2

x1=0
x2=10
y1=1000
y2=100

def luch():
    Canvas.create_rectangle(x1,x2,y1,y2,fill='white')

luch()

photo = PhotoImage(file = "1 враг.gif")
label = Label(image = photo).pack()
fight.mainloop()

w.bind("<Up>", lambda event:up)
w.bind("<Left>", lambda event:left)
w.bind("<Right>", lambda event:right)
w.bind("<Down>", lambda event:down)

def attack_zone():
    kot('kjhkjkl')
    global a1
    global a2
    global b1
    global b2
    global c1
    global c2
    global d1
    global d2
    global x1
    global x2
    global y1
    global y2
    kot('kjhkjkl')
    gorizontal = False
    vertical = False
    if a2<x2 and d2>y2:
        gorizontal = True
    if a1<x1 and d1>y1:
        vertical = True
    if gorizontal and vertical:
        kot("game_over")
    
attack_zone()
```

#НЕ ПЛАГИАТИТЬ КОД

Comment: потому что у тебя перед этим mainloop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю так заработает. Переставил mainloop в конец. Функции пока окно не закрыто после mainloop не будут работать

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from threading import Thread
from playsound import playsound 
kill_boss=False
robot_health = 100


def attack():
    global robot_health,kill_boss
    if robot_health==0:
        kill_boss=True
    else:
        robot_health-=1
    

kill = False

fight = Tk()
fight['bg']='black'
fight.geometry("400x400")
fight.title('Битва')
w = 500
h=500
Canvas = Canvas(bg='black')
Canvas.pack()
def kot(a):
    messagebox.showinfo('Заголовок',a) 
global a1
global a2
global b1
global b2
global c1
global c2
global d1
global d2
a1= 15
a2=15
d1=25
d2=25
c1=a1
c2=d2
b1=d1
b2=d1


player = Canvas.create_rectangle(a1,a2,d1,d2,fill='red')


Button(fight,bg='red',comand=attack()).pack()

def down():
    global a1
    global a2
    global b1
    global b2
    global c1
    global c2
    global d1
    global d2
    Canvas.move(player,0,10)
    d2=+1
    c2=+1
def up():
    global a1
    global a2
    global b1
    global b2
    global c1
    global c2
    global d1
    global d2
    Canvas.move(player,0,-10)
    d2=-10
    c2-=10
def left():
    global a1
    global a2
    global b1
    global b2
    global c1
    global c2
    global d1
    global d2
    Canvas.move(player,-10,0)
    c1=-10
    d1-=10
def right():
    global a1
    global a2
    global b1
    global b2
    global c1
    global c2
    global d1
    global d2
    Canvas.move(player,10,0)
    c1=+10
    d1=+10
global x1
global x2
global y1
global y2
x1=0
x2=10
y1=1000
y2=100
def luch():
    Canvas.create_rectangle(x1,x2,y1,y2,fill='white')

luch()

photo = PhotoImage(file = "1 враг.gif")
label = Label(image = photo).pack()

w.bind("<Up>", lambda event:up)
w.bind("<Left>", lambda event:left)
w.bind("<Right>", lambda event:right)
w.bind("<Down>", lambda event:down)

def attack_zone():
    kot('kjhkjkl')
    global a1
    global a2
    global b1
    global b2
    global c1fight.mainloop()fight.mainloop()
    global c2
    global d1
    global d2
    global x1
    global x2
    global y1
    global y2
    kot('kjhkjkl')
    gorizontal = False
    vertical = False
    if a2<x2 and d2>y2:
        gorizontal = True
    if a1<x1 and d1>y1:
        vertical = True
    if gorizontal and vertical:
        kot("game_over")
    
attack_zone()
fight.mainloop()
#НЕ ПЛАГИАТИТЬ КОД
```